# AlertDialog still visible evenafter dismissed by onClick

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Alert Dialog is visible until the startVibrate() method completes its task but I want to dismiss it as soon as clicked on Ok

```
   AlertDialog.Builder builder = new Builder(VibrationActivity.this);
            builder.setCancelable(false);
            builder.setTitle("Vibration Test");
            builder.setMessage("Your device will vibrate now.");
            builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();   //Dismiss the dialog
                    startVibration();       //Start the test
                }
            });
            builder.show();

    public void startVibration(){
      for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
         try {
              vibrator.vibrate(500); // Vibration time in milliseconds
              Thread.sleep(750); // Interval between two vibration
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: then start that method in separate thread

Comment: @r4jiv007 seperate thread is also not helping me

Comment: try calling your method in AsyncTask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just launch your AlertDialog within your Activity. your Thread should dispatch a message via a handler to the Activity to know when to show and dismiss your Dialog.

Comment: I have used Handler and that is working but I dont want to use handler as it causes memory leaks as my application is bit heavy and any leak will make more difference

Comment: This sound like a design problem then. A Handler should just dispatch/consume a message if you're leaking this stuff then that is a sign of a bigger problem with your app NOT the Handler itself.

Comment: Does it leak if I am using only one message that has target towards that particular Handler and if we send the dispatch to that Handler and does not reference it anywhere??

Answer (score 0):

First call the startVibrate method then dismiss the dialog, better call cancel instead of dismiss.

Comment: I want to close the Dialog as soon as user clicks on Ok not after completion of startVibrate()